# apply addon object shake to a strip

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I would like to use the addon: Object Shake and apply it to a strip.
Is it possible to do that?
How?

https://www.blendernation.com/2018/11/02/free-blender-addon-object-shake/#prettyPhoto

Comment: There are instructions on how to install it on the addons github page: https://github.com/thatimster/object-shake

Comment: thanks I knew how to install it. I am not sure how to apply it to a video strip in VSE. I am just trying to create a shake effect transitioning from one strip to another in the video sequencer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The addon you refer to will add a shake to an object in the 3Dview, it is not setup to work with a strip in the sequencer.

To add some shake to a VSE strip, you can animate the strip offset and use a noise modifier to add random movement. The same technique can be used on any animated value.

Enable the offset option and [insert a keyframe](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/animation/keyframes/editing.html) for the X and/or Y offset value. In 2.7x this can be found under Strip Input.

[image: strip properties]

In the [graph editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/editors/graph_editor/introduction.html), select the keyframed value and add a noise modifier. Increase the strength and adjust other properties to get a suitable variation. Repeat for the other value if you are keying both.

[image: fcurve noise modifer]

To restrict the shake to a portion of the strip you can set the Restrict Frame Range options or you can cut your strip where you want the shake to start and stop and add the noise modifier to the smaller strip.